# check number present in a sequences

Tags: java, algorithm, math, sequence

I am writing a program which I found on a coding competition website, I have sort of figured out how to solve the problem but, I am stuck on a math part of it, I am completely diluting the problem and showing what I need.

first I need to check if a number is part of a sequence, my sequence is `2*a+1` where a is the previous element in the sequence or 2^n-1 to get nth item in the sequence. so it is **1,3,7,15,31,63**...

I don't really want to create the whole sequence and check if a number is present, but I am not sure what a quicker method to do this would be.

Second if I am given a number lets say 25, I want to figure out the next highest number in my sequence to this number. So for 25 it would be 31 and for 47 it would be 63, for 8 it would be 13.

How can i do these things without creating the whole sequence.

I have seen similar questions here with different sequences but I am still not sure how to solve this

Comment: Is the sequence always `coeffiecient * n + offset`? Then it's tremendously ease and can be done in constant time complexity.

Comment: You could see if `n + 1` is a power of two.

Comment: @Blender Your edit seems incorrect. The sequence 1,3,7,15 is 2*a+1, where `a` is the previous number in the sequence.

Comment: @JoeDaley: The `n`th term in the sequence is `2^n - 1`.

Comment: @Blender i meant 2*a+1 only where a is the last element in the sequence

Comment: @Blender My bad, fat fingers :)

Comment: oh i just figured out that there are only 24 elements less than 100000000 which is the limit for the problem, so making the sequence would be the simplest solution but i would still like to know how these types of problem are solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by finding the explicit formula for any term in your sequence. I'm too lazy to write out a proof, so just add `1` to each term in your sequence:

```
 1 + 1 =  2
 3 + 1 =  4
 7 + 1 =  8
15 + 1 = 16
31 + 1 = 32
63 + 1 = 64
...
```

You can clearly see that `a_n = 2^n - 1`.

To check if a particular number is in your sequence, assume that it is:

```
x = 2^n - 1
x + 1 = 2^n
```

From Wikipedia:

> The binary representation of integers makes it possible to apply a
>   very fast test to determine whether a given positive integer x is a
>   power of two:
>
> > positive x is a power of two ⇔ (x & (x − 1)) equals to zero.

So to check, just do:

```
bool in_sequence(int n) {
    return ((n + 1) & n) == 0;
}
```

Comment: what if the number is not in the sequence then how do i find the next highest number in the sequence

Comment: @yahh: Try figuring it out.

Comment: Oh your answer is definitely better than mine! (this even works for `2147483647`)

Answer (score 1):

As @Blender already pointed out your sequence is essentially `2^n - 1`, you can use this trick if you use integer format to store it:

```
boolean inSequence(int value) {
    for (int i = 0x7FFF; i != 0; i >>>= 1) {
        if (value == i) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that for every elements in your sequence, its binary representation will be lots of `0`s and then lots of `1`s.

For example, `7` in binary is `0000000000000000000000000000111` and `63` in binary is `0000000000000000000000000111111`.

This solution starts from `01111111111111111111111111111111` and use an unsigned bitshift, then compare if it is equal to your value.

Nice and simple.

Comment: could you please explain how you got to this solution

Answer (score 0):

**How to find the next higher number :**

For example, we get 19 ( 10011 ) , should return 31 (11111)

```
int findNext(int n){
    if(n == 0) return 1;

    int ret = 2;         // start from 10
    while( (n>>1) > 0){  // end with 100000
        ret<<1;
    }
    return ret-1;
}
```